# Problem with Naive Bootstrapping (US Government Bonds)

Tags: fixed-income, python

I am using the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve#Construction_of_the_full_yield_curve_from_market_data) to determine the discount factor function and eventually the zero-coupon yields. I get the data for Coupons, Face Values and Closing Prices from Thomson Reuters, which I insert into the Dataframe `df`. The code below is used to determine the inverse of the `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues` in the Bootstrapping process. The `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues` prints out exactly as I want it. However, I find that `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues` turns out to be Singular and **I'm trying to figure out if there is an issue with the logic in my code below**. I am using Python 3.4 and part of the Dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
   months_to_maturity                      orig_iss_dt  \
1                   6                    2015-06-25 00:00:00.0   
2                  12                    2015-06-25 00:00:00.0   
3                  18                    2015-06-30 00:00:00.0   
4                  24                    2015-06-15 00:00:00.0   
5                  30                    2015-06-30 00:00:00.0   

             maturity_dt  pay_freq_cd  coupon  closing_price  FACE_VALUE  
1  2015-12-24 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000      99.960889         100  
2  2016-06-23 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000      99.741444         100  
3  2017-06-30 00:00:00.0            2   0.625      99.968750         100  
4  2018-06-15 00:00:00.0            2   1.125     100.390625         100  
5  2020-06-30 00:00:00.0            2   1.625      99.984375         100
```

The code:

```
#Determining the dimensions of the matrix of coupons and face values
#pay_freq_cd is number of coupon payments per year
number_of_columns_and_rows = 0
for (i, row) in df.iterrows():
    no_of_coupons_per_year_2 = row['pay_freq_cd'] 
    no_of_months_between_payments_2 = 12/no_of_coupons_per_year_2
    candidate_number_of_columns_and_rows = row['months_to_maturity']/no_of_months_between_payments_2
    if  candidate_number_of_columns_and_rows > number_of_columns_and_rows:
        number_of_columns_and_rows = candidate_number_of_columns_and_rows
        no_of_months_between_payments_for_matrix = no_of_months_between_payments_2

    matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues = numpy.zeros((number_of_columns_and_rows, number_of_columns_and_rows))      
    #Inserting Coupons and Face values into the Matrix    
    for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
        no_of_coupons_per_year_2 = row['pay_freq_cd']
        no_of_months_between_payments_2 = 12/no_of_coupons_per_year_2
        if math.isnan(no_of_months_between_payments_2):
            matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,0:((number_of_columns_and_rows)-1)] = 0
            matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,(row.months_to_maturity/no_of_months_between_payments_for_matrix)-1] = (row['FACE_VALUE']) + row['coupon']
        else:
            matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,0:((row.months_to_maturity/no_of_months_between_payments_2)-1)] = row['coupon']
            matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,(row.months_to_maturity/no_of_months_between_payments_2)-1] = (row['FACE_VALUE']) + row['coupon']

    inv_matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues = numpy.inv(matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues)
```

Thank You